# Generate subtypes schema in swagger - Minimal Web API

Tags: c#, .net, swagger, minimal-apis

I would like to display the subtypes classes in swagger documentation.
my code:

```
app.MapPost("/search", (BaseType t) =>
{
    return $"property: {t.p1}";
});

public interface BaseType
{ 
    public int p1 { get; set; } 
} 
public class SubTypeA : BaseType 
{
    public int p1 { get; set; }
} 
public class SubTypeB : BaseType
{ 
    public int p1 { get; set; } 
}
```

I only see the BaseType schema. but not the subtypes schema.
Please help :)

I used web api minimal template and enabled OpenAPI tool.

Answer (score 0):

I succeeded to make it work
just added this configuration:

```
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.UseOneOfForPolymorphism();
    c.SelectSubTypesUsing(baseType =>
    {
        if (baseType == typeof(BaseType))
        {
            return new[]
            {
                typeof(SubTypeA),
                typeof(SubTypeB),
            };
        }

        return Enumerable.Empty<Type>();
    });
});
```

Comment: Note that this will not generate discriminator property since `BaseType` is interface. Also note that common convention is to name interfaces starting from `I` -> `IBaseType`.